# How to display node fields in tabs?

Tags: drupal, tabs, drupal-7

I have a content type "activities", which has three fields:

1- Programs
2- Implementation
3- Project Stories

How can I display each field in the node in a separate tab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found an easier way to do it using the [field_group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module. From "Manage Display" the fields can be added to horizontal tabs fieldgroups and then the horizontal tabs fieldgroups can be added to a horizontal tabs group. See the image for further information.[image]

Comment: When I tried this method, the tab was added to #content div rather than the primary tab list.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there are two ways you can achieve this.

1) Using the hook_menu() to create the tabs for your content type.
Here you will have to write your own module and the code will look something like this

```
/**
* Implements hook_menu().
*/
function pages_menu() {
$items['pages'] = array( 
'title' => 'Menu system examples',
'description' => 'Menu system example that returns a string.',
'page callback' => 'pages_string',
'access callback' => TRUE,
);
$items['pages/default'] = array(
'title' => 'String',
'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
'weight' => -10,
);
$items['pages/render-array'] = array(
'title' => 'Render array',
'description' => 'Menu system example using a render array.',
'page callback' => 'pages_render_array',
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
'weight' => 2,
'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
 );
 $items['pages/render-array/tab1'] = array(
'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
'title' => 'Tab 1',
 );
 $items['pages/render-array/tab2'] = array( 
'title' => 'Tab 2',
'description' => 'Demonstrating secondary tabs.',
'page callback' => 'pages_render_array',
'access callback' => TRUE,
'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
 );

 return $items; 
 }
```

You then use the call back function to do your think in each of the tabs

2) Using Css and jquery to style the content in a way that it looks like a tab.

here is a great working demo for you. http://www.99points.info/2010/08/create-sexy-animated-tabs-using-jquery-and-css/

Cheers,
Vishal

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on Drupal moduels gets this:

D6 - http://drupalmodules.com/module/cck-fieldgroup-tabs
D7 - http://drupal.org/project/field_group

Answer (score 0):

One other module to consider, if anyone else comes looking for an answer: http://drupal.org/project/node_subpages

[[shameless plug]]